# RPI 3 B+ configured as wireless extender (AP + client) troubleshooting

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, pi-3b+, hostapd

Im trying to configure my RPi 3 B+ as a wireless extender using the internal wifi chip aacting as the client and AP. Ive been following this guide as it seems most suitable for os/model/application https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=211542#p1355569

Ive been trying for longer than id like to admit to make this work :oops:  , had a look at all the how-to's and troubleshooting i can find but keep running into errors

OS:  Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)

kernel:   4.14.98-v7+

after reboot or running systemctl restart hostapd wlan0 up and running uap0 says not associated in the GUI and this is the result  :?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -xe
Apr 15 17:52:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 15 17:52:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
-- Subject: Unit hostapd.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit hostapd.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator...
-- Subject: Unit hostapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit hostapd.service has begun starting up.
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi hostapd[3500]: Configuration file: DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi hostapd[3500]: Could not open configuration file 'DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"' for reading.
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi hostapd[3500]: Failed to set up interface with DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi hostapd[3500]: Failed to initialize interface
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 15 17:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
-- Subject: Unit hostapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit hostapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

Any help much appreciated! let me know if any other info can help troubleshoot  :)

Answer (score 1):

The WiFi device on the Raspberry Pi is a bit complicated and maybe also a bit buggy or its driver. You have to follow exactly a startup sequence to get it to work:

1. create a virtual interface `ap0` for the access point
2. start access point daemon `hostapd` using interface `ap0`
3. start `wpa_supplicant` for wifi client using interface `wlan0`

This order restricts the whole setup. I have seen many hacks that try to solve it but didn't understood this background. An answer to this problem you can find at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).